# convert curl request with --cacert to dotnet HttpClient

Tags: c#, curl, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following curl request which contains a client certificate, key and cacert

```
curl https://insert_url_here --key transport.key --cert transport.pem --cacert ca.cer
```

I want to be able to convert this into C# but am struggling to get it to work with the --cacert. I have the following code to create my HttpClient and make the http request

```
public async Task MakeHttpRequest()
{
    using (var httpClient = CreateClient())
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://insert_url_here");
    }
}


public HttpClient CreateClient()
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(TRANSPORT_CERT);
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (req, cert, chain, err) =>
    {
        // should i check the ca here?!
        return true;
    };
    return new HttpClient(handler);
}
```

Note: I have merged my transport.key / transport.pem into a transport.pfx.

Where I am struggling is verifying the cacert, the curl request works without issue but I receive a certificate error in .net `RemoteCertificateChainErrors`. I am unable to put the cacert in the trusted store so how can i verify without doing that in my `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`? X509Chain? If so how...

Comment: Well, `cert` parameter in callback represents remote certificate, so you can validate it there.

Comment: @Evk yeah that was where i was thinking i needed to do it, do you know how you would do it? X509Chain?

Comment: Usually you just verify that hash of this certificate is what you expect. But in your case as I understand, `ca.cer` is some certificate upper in the trust chain so yes, you need to use another parameter representing chain. Just run your code with debugger and inspect what's inside `chain`, that will give you a clue how to perform validation.